# Ionic 3 Animating background image - Motion plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Has anyone seen a tutorial or an explanation on how it’s possible to “animate” your background image with the motion of the Phone? You know in some apps, when you move the phone up/down/left/right, the background image seems to also move a bit, creating a very nice dynamic feel to the app. I haven’t seen anywhere how this can be achieved.

I would guess there’s something to do with https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device-motion/ plugin, but not sure how to connect all the dots.

Any advice?